# How to Move My Page into WordPress dashboard main menu

Tags: pages, admin-menu, dashboard

I am new to WordPress development, hope this is not a too stupid question.

I want to Move my "Camp" Page(that appear Under Pages -> Camp) into Dashboard Main menu,

if its not possible to move page then tell me how to create shortcut in main menu

see the below screenshot[image]

I don't want to create custom post type because when i click the "Camp" I want to display(see the below screenshot)

[image]

**EDIT**

After Added this code

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', function() {
    add_submenu_page(
        'edit.php?post_type=page',
        'camp',
        'camp',
        'edit_pages',
        'post.php?post=128&action=edit'
    );
});
```

It's look like

[image]

now my Question is How to Display 'camp' after my custom post types.

For Example i want to display this order

1) Testimonials

2) Reviews

3) camp

Which slug to use in,

```
$parent_slug,
```

Comment: I could be wrong but I seriously doubt this is possible.  Frankly, you are asking someone to invest no small amount of time to save you two clicks for editing a page.  Find the ID of your "camp" page and create a browser bookmark instead: http://domainname/wp-admin/post.php?post=IDFORPAGE&action=edit. That will always load the edit screen for your page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used

> add_menu_page

function to achieve the solution

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'register_my_custom_menu_page' );

function register_my_custom_menu_page() {
    add_menu_page( 
        'camp', 
        'Camp', 
        'edit_pages', 
        'post.php?post=128&action=edit', 
        '', 
        'dashicons-admin-home', 
        11 
    );
}
```

After use this code,

[image]

In the above screen shot 'Camp' Appear in Dashboard Perfectly

This is Exactly what i am needed

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the browser’s address bar on that page’s edit screen, you see something like this:

```
wp-admin/post.php?post=91&action=edit
```

The `91` is the post id. This is the important information, you can create a sub menu page for that now.

To add a page to the the admin menu, use the hook `admin_menu` and the function `add_submenu_page()`. Set the page menu as parent and the URL of the *Camp* page as menu URL:

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', function() {
    add_submenu_page(
        'edit.php?post_type=page',
        'Camp',
        'Camp',
        'edit_pages',
        'post.php?post=91&action=edit'
    );
});
```

That’s all. :)

Comment: Your fix is working, but i have another doubt, i updated my question please check